# Undefined collision in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am using Angular 8 with `"typescript": "~3.5.3"`. Trying to do the undefined collision

```
const { testLocation } = this.ngr.getState();
    this.step2 = testLocation && testLocation.step2 ? testLocation.step2 : {};
    this.$form = this.fb.group({
      // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
      email: [this.step2.email || '', [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$')]],
      phone: [this.step2.phone || ''],
      configuration: this.fb.group({
        idTypesAccepted: this.buildIdentityDocumentTypeFormArr(this.identityDocumentType),

        sessionOpenDays: [this.step2.configuration.sessionOpenDays || '', Validators.required],
        sessionOpenHours: [this.step2.configuration.sessionOpenHours || '', Validators.required],
        sessionOpenMinutes: [this.step2.configuration.sessionOpenMinutes || '', Validators.required],

        sessionCloseDays: [this.step2.configuration.sessionCloseDays || '', Validators.required],
      sessionCloseHours: [this.step2.configuration.sessionCloseHours || '', Validators.required],
        sessionCloseMinutes: [this.step2.configuration.sessionCloseMinutes || '', Validators.required],

        applicationExpiryDays: [this.step2.configuration.applicationExpiryDays || '', Validators.required],
        applicationExpiryHours: [this.step2.configuration.applicationExpiryHours || '', Validators.required],
        applicationExpiryMinutes: [this.step2.configuration.applicationExpiryMinutes || '', Validators.required],

        paymentCloseDays: [this.step2.configuration.paymentCloseDays || '', Validators.required],
        paymentCloseHours: [this.step2.configuration.paymentCloseHours || '', Validators.required],
        paymentCloseMinutes: [this.step2.configuration.paymentCloseMinutes || '', Validators.required]
      })
    });
```

In the above code `this.step2.configuration`, configuration is undefined. How can I surpass this. I need to fill up either empty value or value from then `this.step2.configuration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only three ways I see here is either:
Check for undefined at start and override with dummy model

```
this.step2 = testLocation && testLocation.step2 ? testLocation.step2 : {};
if(!this.step2.configuration) {
  this.step2.configuration = new Configuration(); // filling the blanks with a dummy data model which has nulled or '' variables;
}
```

alternatively duplicate the entire formbuilding

```
if(!this.step2.configuration) {
  this.fb.group({
    sessionOpenDays: ['', Validators.required],
    [...]
  });
  return;
}
this.fb.group({[...]});
```

or you could switch to Angular 10 (not sure which version of 9 introduced this, but it certainly is available on 10)

```
this.step2 = testLocation && testLocation.step2 ? testLocation.step2: {};
this.fb.group({
  sessionOpenDays: [this.step2.configuration?.sessionOpenDays || '', Validators.required],
[...]
});
```

in angular 10, just like it (almost) always was in the html-templates, a questionmark checks if the property is availabe and if not, initializes the formControl with a `null` value. Be aware though that a direct call to the form field would also yield null instead of '' then.